# ASP.NET MVC Global or BaseController ActionFilter to Execute Before OnAuthorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization, actionfilterattribute, authorize-attribute

In my application (ASP.NET MVC 3) I have a BaseController class that all my Controllers inherit and in that BaseController I have overridden the OnActionExecuting method to check to ensure a Session variable is populated as I need access to that in all other action methods in the application.  I also have a custom Authorize attribute that I have defined that extends the AuthorizeAttributeClass.  In that attribute I override OnAuthorization to check the same Session variable I am loading in the BaseController OnActionExecuting method to see if the user should be permitted to continue.

BaseController

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private ISessionUserService sessionUserService;

    public BaseController(ISessionUserService sessionUserService)
    {
        this.sessionUserService = sessionUserService;            
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        if (User != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && this.sessionUserService.Current == null)
        {                     
            this.sessionUserService.Start(accountID, User.Identity.Name);                                                                           

            // If we weren't successful in reloading the SessionUser
            // variable, redirect the user to the Sign In view
            if (this.sessionUserService.Current == null)
            {                  
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(Url.Action("SignIn", "Access", new { area = string.Empty }));
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Custom Authorize Attribute

```
public class AuthorizeByPermission : AuthorizeAttribute
{        
    public Permission[] Permissions { get; set; }

    public AuthorizeByPermission(params Permission[] permissions)
    {
        this.Permissions = permissions;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        SessionUser sessionUser = filterContext.HttpContext.Session.Get<SessionUser>();

        if (sessionUser.HasPermission(Permissions))
            return;

        filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the BaseController OnActionExecuting method is firing AFTER the OnAuthorization method in my AuthorizeByPermission attribute and I need it to be the other way arround as the BaseController needs to popualte the Session variable if it isn't there before the authorize attribute attempts to access it.

Basically I need to find a way to have a base class method or a global filter that can be registered to occur before the OnAuthorization method fires.  Any ideas on how to do this?

I have tried registering a GlobalFilter to load the session variable and set its Order property to be lower than the AuthorizeByPermission attribute but that didn't seem to work either.

I have also tried overriding the Execute method in the BaseController and that actually fired before the custom authorization attribute but the problem was that I didn't have access to the filterContext which allowed me to redirect the user to the SignIn page if we couldn't load the session variable.

As per bmosh's comment I tried turning my BaseController OnActionExecuting method into a separate filter and decorate the BaseController with that attribute with a lower Order number than the AuthorizeByPermission attribute but it still didn't work.

```
[FilterIWantToFireFirst(Order = 1)]
public class BaseController : Controller
{

}

public class AnotherController : BaseController
{
     [AuthorizeByPermission(Permission.Add, Order = 2)]
     public ActionResult SomeActionMethod() 
     {
     }
}
```

Even with the above setup, the AuthorizeByPermission attribute is fired first.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use `Session` for authentication. [It's wildly insecure.](http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2009/06/14/session-attacks-and-aspnet-part-1/) `Session` is a user-specific cache, not an authentication framework.

Comment: Its better than hitting the database to retrieve permissions on every single request isn't it?  And it is definitely better than storing permission in a cookie on the client.  Do you have another way to store user permissions for quick repeated access without having to go to the database every time. (Built in ASP.NET security is not an option)

Comment: You should be able to add a filter attribute to your BaseController and give the filter a higher priority than the Authorize filter using the order property

Comment: @Nick: I disagree with you on both points. Security is the *sole reason* to do authentication and authorization. Faster != better if it's not secure! Hell, I can go faster than session; `IsAdministrator = true` executes in blinding speed! Second, storing permissions in a cookie on the client isn't actually bad, if done securely. The server can sign and [encrypt the cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.encrypt.aspx) such that the client can neither read it nor alter it; it can only hand back what it has been given.

Comment: With all that said: Whenever anyone says the built-in authentication won't work and proposes something dangerously insecure as an alternative (and it happens several times a day here) I wonder if "won't work" actually means "seems like less work to me since I haven't actually done the hard work of making my alternative rock solid."

Comment: @Craig: I do appreciate your comments and will take them into serious consideration although I can't help but feel like your accusing me of murder!  It isn't always possible to detect tone when using a medium of communication as this but it came across loud and clear from you.

Comment: To be clear: I am not questioning your motivations, or accusing you of anything. The brutal truth with security is that one weak link makes the whole chain useless. Always go with a proven, off the shelf solution, even if it *seems* like more work. The only good reasons to write your own are as a throwaway learning exercise or if you'd like to plan on spending years and years having it vetted by experts.

Comment: Note that we are using the off the shelf forms authentication. The only thing we are implementing ourselves is authorization via permissions due to the fact that the default role provider will not work for our needs.  We actually spent a long time trying to get it to work with the required features and it proved to not work at all. We are utilizing the default Authorize attribute to ensure they are authenticated and a custom attribute to authorize them to perform various actions.

Comment: If you want to understand filter ordering, read my article Filtering in ASP.NET MVC http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx  - You should listen to what Craig writes, he's not overstating the security risk.

Answer (score 4):

You could try overriding OnAuthorization instead of OnActionExecuting in your base controller.